# I am trying to make text slide from one side of a website to the other side and then disappear

Tags: html

I am trying to make a website that shows some text going right to left.

A good example of what I am trying to make is the background on this website [realtimebitcoin.info](https://realtimebitcoin.info/). 
I am not quite sure where to start. 
Any advice would be much appreciated.
 
Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: As far as I understand, you want to animate background as in  realtimebitcoin.info website?

Comment: Yes. But I'm not sure how to start or what language to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be tempted to use the marquee tag, which will animate your text in a way like you wish. However, that tag is deprecated and might give unanticipated results in different browsers. Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e4f930qf/6/)
HTML

```
<span>Hello World</span>
```

CSS

```
span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  animation: marquee 3s infinite;
}
@keyframes marquee {
  0% {left: 500px}
  50% {left: 200px}
  100% {left: -100px}
}
```

Play around with the animation keyframe to get the exact scroll effect you desire.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.animated {
  position:relative;
  animation: animate 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes animate{
  0% {left: 100%}
  100% {left: 0%}
}
```

```html
<div class="animated">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem sapiente quisquam optio iusto consectetur recusandae voluptatibus quis mollitia dolore vitae perspiciatis, doloribus cumque, incidunt corporis, labore veritatis asperiores aliquid animi.</div>
```